# Including paramaters only for the purpose of exception reporting in inner functions

Tags: c#, .net, exception, parameter-passing

```
CreateDocument(string templatePath)
{
    Document doc = OpenDocument(templatePath);
    Picture pic = GetLogo();
    AddLogo(doc, pic, templatePath);
}

AddLogo(Document doc, Picture logo, string templatePath)
{
    Picture placeholder = doc.FindLogoPlaceholder();
    if (placeholder.Size != logo.Size)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(
            String.Format("Invalid template {0}, logo size: {1}, required: {2}",
                 templatePath, placeholder.Size, logo.Size
            ));
    }
}
```

Consider the above code as an example I just made up.

Notice that the only reason `templatePath` is passed into the `AddLogo` method is to facilitate exception generation.

I have something in my code today where I needed to do this, and it feels like a really nasty code smell to me. But I'm not too familiar with exception handling patterns and I don't really see any better way to do it.

I'm wondering what your thoughts are and if there is a better pattern to dealing with situations like this.

Comment: Does `Document` expose a property of the path that it opened in the `OpenDocument` call?  If so it would negate the need for parameter-passing for the purposes of exceptions, which I agree fell out of the ugly tree and hit every branch on the way down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the exception on a higher level:

```
CreateDocument(string templatePath)
{
    Document doc = OpenDocument(templatePath);
    Picture pic = GetLogo();
    try {
        AddLogo(doc, pic);
    } catch (InvalidLogoSize e) {
        throw new ApplicationException(
            String.Format("Invalid template {0}, logo size: {1}, required: {2}",
                 templatePath, e.pSize, e.lSize
            ));
    }
}

AddLogo(Document doc, Picture logo)
{
    Picture placeholder = doc.FindLogoPlaceholder();
    if (placeholder.Size != logo.Size)
    {
        throw new InvalidLogoSizeException(placeholder.Size, logo.Size);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include the original exception as inner exception or you will loose part of the stack trace.

Comment: +1 for throwing an ApplicationException. In the catch clause of CreateDocument I would set the original exception as the inner exception to the newly thrown exception. That enables tracing back to the point where the actual problem occurred.

Comment: @Marnix: why +1 for throwing `ApplicationException`? I'm pretty sure ApplicationException is considered too general in most cases. FxCop certainly moans about it.

Comment: ApplicationException is deprecated (see Jeffrey Richter in "Framework Design Guidelines", Cwalina & Adams 2006). Microsoft broke their own rules for using ApplicationException in the .Net framework by deriving from it when they should have derived from SystemException, so ApplicationException is broken.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: It's a best practice not to throw System.Exception but a derived type that is more specific to your application. That allows you (or anybody consuming your code) to catch specific exceptions and act accordingly. I wasn't aware the ApplicationException was considered depricated though.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically throw the exception, then catch it at any layer where you can add more information, wrap it in a new exception and throw that one.

Answer (score 1):

The caller of the function can catch an rethrow with additional information:

```
CreateDocument(string templatePath) 
{ 
    Document doc = OpenDocument(templatePath); 
    Picture pic = GetLogo(); 
    try
    {
        AddLogo(doc, pic);
    }
    catch(Excpetion e)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException( templatePath, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It occured to me as soon as I posted the question that this is what I should be doing! :)